# How to catch the params of the custom protocol in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, protocols, custom-protocol

As the title mentioned, how could I cache or know the parameters of the custom protocol in Chrome?

Every time the popup comes up and I have no method to know what will pass to the custom application(protocol handler), I think it is very risky and untransparent.

If the Chrome could not show the information, is there any browsers supports this?